# Dimension of certain type of finitely generated $k$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, binomial-ideals

Let $k$ be any field. I want to determine the (Krull) dimension of the following rings:

(i) $k[x,y,z]/(x^3-1)$,

(ii) $k[x,y,z]/(x^2-y^4,x-y^3)$ and

(iii) $k[x,y,z]/(x^3-1,x^2y^4-1,x^2y^3-z^5)$.

I realise in the all the cases $(x-1,y-1,z-1)$ is a maximal ideal containing the quotiented ideal. But how do I determine the dimension from this.

I am actually trying to determine the coheight ($\dim A/I$) of binomial ideals in $k[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$. So is there a general method to determine the dimensions above so that I can use it in the general case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the last example, you should notice that $y^5-x$ is contained in the ideal, i.e. the ideal is $(y^5-x,y^{15}-1,y^{14}-1,y^{13}-z^5)=(y^5-x,y-1,z^5-1)=(x-1,y-1,z^5-1)$.

Comment: Everything you need is: If $R$ is noetherian, then $\dim R[t] = 1+\dim R$. $\dim k[t]/(f)=0$ for $f \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tool 1**
 A polynomial ring over a noetherian ring $A$ has dimension : $$\operatorname {dim}A[T_1,\cdots ,T_n]=\operatorname {dim}A+n$$ **Tool 2**
Let $k$ be a field with algebraically closure $\bar k$ and let $I$ be an ideal $I\subset  k[T_1,\cdots,T_n]$. Then $$\operatorname {dim} \frac {k[T_1,\cdots,T_n]}{I}=0 \iff V(I)\subset \mathbb A^n(\bar k)=\bar k^n \quad \text {is finite}$$ 
**Answer to (i)** $$  \operatorname {dim}k[x,y,z]/(x^3-1)=\operatorname {dim}_k( \frac {k[x]}{(x^3-1)})[y,z]=0+2=2$$ where the second equality follows from Tools 1 and 2.
**Answer to (ii)**
We have $k[x,y,z]/(x^2-y^4,x-y^3)=k[y,z]/(y^6-y^4)=\frac {k[y]}{(y^6-y^4)}[z]$ which, by the same reasoning as in (i), has dimension $0+1=1$
**Answer to (iii)**
Tool 2 immediately implies that the ring $k[x,y,z]/(x^3-1,x^2y^4-1,x^2y^3-z^5)$ has dimension $0$, since $V(x^3-1,x^2y^4-1,x^2y^3-z^5)\subset \bar k^3$ contains $3\cdot 4\cdot 5=60$ points.